# React - Wrap dev server output

Tags: php, reactjs

I am new to react and notice that the dev server is running at mywebsite:3000. That's fine, but it doesn't wrap the application in my CSS or other structural elements, such as the header, footer, navigation. It's just a blank page with the app.

Instead, I want to develop inside the structure of my website with all of the normal elements included, preferably so I don't have to import these into my react project.

I'm using php to serve APIs and the site itself, as well as vanilla create react app (not ejected).

Does this sound like there is a way to accomplish this?

---

Edit: To clarify further... imagine that you have a wordpress site. In order to get the "built" version of your react project to appear, you simply do a file_get_contents($pathToBuildFolder); inside of a page template in order to show the react project to your users. It appears within your website, surrounded by the header, footer, navigation, etc... This works because it's just grabbing the index.html file and outputting it where content would normally go.

So then, how could that same thing be accomplished with the dev server? I want to see the output of the dev server WITHIN my actual website where the content normally goes while I'm developing.

Comment: Could you make a simple diagram of what you're looking to achieve? Do you have other elements from a non-React app that you're trying to include?

Comment: @Atav32 I edited my question to hopefully explain this better. I have elements from a PHP website (wordpress) that I'm trying to include around the react app. Thanks

Comment: It may be possible, but it's hard to tell without seeing your exact setup. Do you have a public Github repo?

Comment: Also, it sounds like this'll take some Webpack configuration. How familiar are you with Webpack loaders?

Comment: @Atav32 It's not something I can publicly host unfortunately. I'll see if I can host a simplified example though. I am familiar with react-app-rewired (to modify webpack config), but I'm not very versed on webpack itself.

Comment: From what it sounds like, you'll probably have to eject Webpack from Create React App and tell it to load a different `index.html` as the template. Then you'll want to modify `index.js` to change the DOM target that the app renders on.

Comment: And instead of using the dev server, you'll probably want an unminified production build that gets placed into your build folder so the PHP server can find it.

Comment: @Atav32 These concepts are not something I had even considered, so I'm going to see where that gets me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy to help! Thinking about it a bit more. If you go the route of using Webpack to put an (unminified) production bundle into the build folder for your PHP server, then I don't think you'll need to change the `index.html` in the Webpack config. You'll just want to change the target of `ReactDOM.render()` to be some container element in your PHP template. And then load the React app JS bundle (either as a script tag or with a PHP function).

Comment: Because the output of Webpack is a Javascript bundle, you should be able to include it like a JS library.

Comment: You won't get any of the nice dev features of Webpack's dev server (automatic reloading, hot module replacement, etc), but it should render inside your current template. You could add a watch task to the Webpack prod config so that it'll rebuild every time you edit the React app src code.